# Add product to favorite with font awesome heart icon toggle (MVC)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I need an `ActionResult` for adding my products by id to users fav. page.
I used jquery to toggle between two icons. But I don't know how to pass product id to controller. Here are my codes:

This is my view that has the product id:

```
<a href="#" id="addWish" class="like" product="@item.id">
  <i class="fa fa-heart-o" style="color:red;" id="wishlist"></i>
</a>
```

Here is my jquery script:

```
<script>
  function addFav() {
    var productId = $(this).attr("product");
    $.ajax({
      url: "~/home/AddToFav",
      data: { "id": productId },
      success: function() {
        $('i#wishlist')
          .addClass('active')
          .attr('class', 'fa fa-heart-o')
          .unbind('click')
          .bind('click', removeFav);
      }
    });
  }
  function removeFav() {
    var productId = $(this).attr("product");
    $.ajax({
      url: "~/home/RemoveFromFav",
      data: { "id": productId },
      success: function() {
        $('i#wishlist')
          .removeClass('active')
          .attr('class', 'fa fa-heart')
          .unbind('click')
          .bind('click', addFav);
      }
    });
  }
  //this will make the link listen to function
  // addFav (you might know this already)
  $('a#wishlist').bind('click', addFav);
</script>
```

**UPDATE**

This is the generated html that i want to manage:

```
<a href="#" class="addWish like" data-product="13">
  <i class="fa fa-heart-o" style="color:red;" id="wishlist"></i>
</a>
<a href="#" class="addWish like" data-product="12">
  <i class="fa fa-heart-o" style="color:red;" id="wishlist"></i>
</a>
<a href="#" class="addWish like" data-product="11">
  <i class="fa fa-heart-o" style="color:red;" id="wishlist"></i>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I don't think you need two functions for adding and removing.. Instead one function should decide whether to add or remove. E.g. if it is already in the users fav list, remove it or else add it..

Secondly, you will also need some kind of a list_id or a user_id so that the method knows which user you are trying to update

Thirdly, for your a tag: append data- to the product as below. Also, I believe you have more than one  tags. So instead of an id use a class name to identify the clicked one..

```
<a href="#" class="addWish like" data-product="@item.id">
  <i class="fa fa-heart-o" style="color:red;" id="wishlist"></i>
</a>
```

then wrap your function inside the click event of the a tag.

```
$('.addWish').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var el = $(this),
    icon = el.find('i'), // <-- new
    productId = el.data("product"),
    some_user_id = 3; // get user id.. 
  $.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("toggleFavorite", "User")',
    data: {
      "id": productId,
      "user_id": some_user_id
    },
    done: function(result) {
      // our methods return true or false
      if (result) {
        alert('added to fav');
        icon.removeClass().addClass('fa fa-heart-o'); // <-- new
      } else {
        alert('removed from fav');
        icon.removeClass().addClass('fa fa-heart'); // <-- new
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Then in your controller;

```
public JsonResult toggleFavorite(int id, int user_id)
{
    // your db logic to check if the id is already in favourites
    // for this specific user.
    // then return true or false (or whatever) depending on your
    // requirements for this specific scenario assume we return
    // true: if we added
    // false: if we removed
    var result = // your db outcome
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: it has some issues 1- i used "success:" instead of "done:" , 2 - in result when i change the icon all icons changes not the specific one,

Comment: 1-OK, 2-What do you mean "change the icon"? If I got it correctly, you are not referring to "that spesific" icon so, I updated my answer to include an "icon" variable too. check to see if its ok..

Comment: i mean change the <i class="fa fa-heart-o"> to <i class="fa fa-heart"> of only that row that i clicked (data-product). now it changes all "fa-heart-o" to "fa-heart".

Comment: check now please.. and do not use an id on the icon <i/> tag.. you are probably repeating rows and ending up with multiple identical IDs..

Comment: yes i repeat the <a> with <i> in it and i have to select by <a> tag cause it has that unique  "product id" and don't know how.

Comment: yes i checked its not working.i updated the question my friened.

Comment: You have three </i> tags with the same ID !!!!!!! You don't need ID for the <i/> tag! When I say icon = el.find('i'); in the above updated answer, I am already referring that spesific icon.. If still you are having problems, please create a fiddle as I am suspecting you are selecting the <i/> tags by ID hence there are three of them